# htaccess redirect if url contains word on changed url

Tags: .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, redirect, url-rewriting

If my url will like this:

```
http://id.factor.ua/bez-rubriki/checkout/?price=...
```

And url will contains **bez-rubriki**

How I can redirect using .htaccess to this url BUT without this slug, like next URL:

```
http://id.factor.ua/checkout/?price=...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As simple as this for an internal rewrite:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^bez-rubriki/checkout/$ /checkout/ [L,QSA]
```

For an external redirection add the `R` flag:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^bez-rubriki/checkout/$ /checkout/ [R=301,L,QSA]
```

The above are the versions to be used inside `.htaccess` style files.

A general note: if you have control over the http server configuration, then you should always prefer to place such rules inside the host configuration instead of using .htaccess style files. Those files are notoriously error prone, make things complex, are hard to debug and really slow the server down. They should only be used if there is *no* control of the http server configuration or if some app requires dynamic changes to the configuration.

So in case you want to place those rules in the host configuration you need a small modification. You have to include the leading slash (`/`) into the regex testing the request path:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/bez-rubriki/checkout/$ /checkout/ [L,QSA]
```

And the version doing an external redirection:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/bez-rubriki/checkout/$ /checkout/ [R=301,L,QSA]
```

Comment: it doesn't work. but thankyou I try it on the next [link](http://portalchik.factor.ua/bez-rubriki/checkout/?price=399%2C00&izd=%D0%9D%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%20%D0%B8%20%D0%B1%D1%83%D1%85%D0%B3%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9%20%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82&vidp=%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%20%D1%81%20%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%80%D1%8C%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9%20%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9&imagr=%2Fimagesizdania%2F1.png#izdanija)

Comment: "doesn't work" is not a helpful comment. What does that mean? You get an error? Nothing happens? The universe implodes? Apart from that: are .htaccess style files interpreted at all by the http server? You have to enable that feature first. And where have you placed that file?

Comment: "Nothing happens" - you can try it when go to the link what in my first comment

Comment: The above rules do not redirect, they only rewrite internally, as you requested. So the url in the browser won't change. What makes you believe that the rules do not work? And sorry, no, that link does not help me to understand. I ask again: _did you enable .htaccess style files_ on your http server / for that location?

Comment: Yes, it interpreted at all by the http server yet. I put it in root directory, where placed my index.php

Comment: The rule is fine and does what you requested. There must be some other issue. Really no errors in the http servers error log? If so, what are they?  If not, I suggest you enable rewrite logging in your server. It tells you exactly what is going on inside the rewriting engine.

Comment: Oh, you really took the _first_ code block and not the _second_ variant I added? You need the _first_ for .htaccess style files.

Comment: I try all variant but now in my .htaccess file putting first! I really cannot doing myself and ask u more successes guys in it! BUT now result - nothing changed!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51649/discussion-between-arkascha-and-serge)

Comment: Based on the details from the chat I added the `R` flag to the answer to allow an external redirect.

Comment: can I ask one question??

Comment: As always: never "ask to ask", just ask instead ;-) I entered that chat room from above again...